# How to convert large numbers stored as objects to numeric (int) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, largenumber

I have some large numbers (stored as `object`s) in a pandas dataframe and would like to convert them to numeric types (say, `int`). However, these numbers seem to be too large for `np.int64` and I was struggling to find an acceptable solution.

```
d = {'col1': [2, 0], 'col2': ['51578544061302681992337164', '3323221002002020200202020202']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

`df['col1'].astype(int)` works as expected but:

- `df['col2'].astype(int)` and `df['col2'].astype(np.int64)` throw `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`
- `pd.to_numeric(df['col2'])` throws `ValueError: Integer out of range. at position 0`
- `df['col2'].astype(np.longdouble)` throws no error but appears to reduce the precision of the numbers.

I think what I am looking for is an int128 data type.

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Comments from numpy developers regarding adding int128 and uint128 support: <https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9992>

Answer (score 0):

While you can't convert the strings to numpy dtypes, you can convert them to Python ints.

```
In [139]: df.to_numpy()
Out[139]: 
array([[2, '51578544061302681992337164'],
       [0, '3323221002002020200202020202']], dtype=object)
In [140]: df['col3']=[int(x) for x in df['col2']]
In [141]: df
Out[141]: 
   col1                          col2                          col3
0     2    51578544061302681992337164    51578544061302681992337164
1     0  3323221002002020200202020202  3323221002002020200202020202
In [142]: df.to_numpy()
Out[142]: 
array([[2, '51578544061302681992337164', 51578544061302681992337164],
       [0, '3323221002002020200202020202', 3323221002002020200202020202]],
      dtype=object)
```

Pandas displays the strings and ints in the same way.